# React Native ScrollView scrollToEnd({duration: 5000}) not working - Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to make a ScrollView that will auto scroll to bottom in some time. But instead it is instantly scrolling to bottom.

```
moveScreen = () =>{
this.scrollViewRef.flashScrollIndicators();
this.scrollViewRef.scrollToEnd({duration: 5000, animated: true});}

setScrollViewRef = (element) => {
this.scrollViewRef = element;};

render(){
return (
  <View style={{height:'100%', width:'100%',flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <ScrollView ref={this.setScrollViewRef} style={{height:'100%',width:'90%'}} onContentSizeChange={()=> this.moveScreen()}>
      {balloonList}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={{height:'100%',width:'10%',justifyContent:'flex-end',}}>{bucketList}</View>
  </View>
);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather try using setTimeout with the duration you want, ive achieved like that.,

```
setTimeout(() => this.scrollViewRef.scrollToEnd({duration: 500, animated: true}) , 1000);
```

and here 1000ms is my time, you can provide any time. Hope its clear, othewise ask any doubts.

Comment: It is scrolling to end after 1 sec (because of timeout) but after that it is scrolling down  instantly. I want it to take total 5 sec in scrolling to bottom.

Comment: can you try duration of 5000. 500 is rather less than 1 sec. so replace 500 with 5000.

Comment: I did that and it is not working. I edited the question also.

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing the functionality of this implementation on an iOS device it is not possible to add the `duration` option and it will immediately scroll to the end regardless of what value is passed.

> For Android, you may specify a duration, e.g. scrollToEnd({duration: 500}) for a controlled duration scroll.

See the docs for more information: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrolltoend

EDIT:

Turns out this feature was actually ready to be shipped but ended up breaking some internal callsites and ended up being reverted however the docs still mention it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/22884#issuecomment-510846680